# Ubuntu 18 ans 20 freeze and restart randomly

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, freeze, restart

I am using Ubuntu 18. Since 2 days ubuntu restarts randomly - does not matter if I'm doing something at the mement or if I just left my laptop unattended for hours. It freezes, the mouse does not move, everything is unresposnsive and then restarts. I took it for a hardware check, the guys said it has no problems at all, changed the hard drive with one of theirs(with Windows) and it apparantly ran smoothly.
I tried reinstalling Ubuntu 18 and about an hour later got the same problem. Then I tried switching to Ubuntu 20. It seemed fine at the beginning for about 12 hours, then started randomly freezing and restarting again.
My machine is Lenovo ThinkPad E570 with Intel Core i7-7500U CPU at 2.7 GHz.
My Kernel Version (with Ubuntu 20 now) is 5.8.0-50-generic

I put down the kern.log and syslog.I didn't see anything to help me there, but thruth is I am not sure what to look for. There was a restart at 7:13h if that is relevant.
I would appreciate any help!

Syslog:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/18geWj0GJWtS6kbvHfelIuGhd9w9HKl6o/view?usp=sharing

Kern.log:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/15ZHLZvEugVL_ZfgXZ5ohXVqwugkQ5eft/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Ubuntu have different products; releases using the *yy* format are all *snap* only (eg. Ubuntu Core 18), and products using the *yy.mm* format are *deb* based but can also use snaps (eg. Ubuntu 18.04 LTS).  You mention both products where they are very different. Please be precise (Ubuntu Core 18 is built on 18.04 but it's cut down & smaller, which is a benefit to devices/cloud-use etc but it also has a smaller function set).  Please clarify if you're talking about 18 or 18.04, 20 or 20.04 as they are different products.

Comment: Reads more like hardware issues to me, but your mixing of different products in detail, and lack of specifics (did SysRq commands work? was it desktop? server? if GUI was the gui just frozen?, memtest ran how many cycles? etc) implies you've not likely been very thorough, at least to me...

Answer (score 1):

Note how your syslog did NOT log any normal shutdown activity warning before the 0713 restart. It didn't terminate the network connection. It didn't unmount the disks. It didn't progress through the systemd targets, finally reaching shutdown.target.

That's conclusive. It means the trigger did not come from Ubuntu.

Therefore the cause is likely hardware. "*Random freezing and restarts*" are classic symptoms of hardware failure.

Were the issue overheating, I would expect to see log entries showing CPU throttling or other heat-related warnings. None in the log. However, speculation about hardware troubleshooting is outside the scope of AskUbuntu.

Advice: Take it to a different hardware shop, and leave it there until they experience the same unexplained restart. Alternately, swap out components yourself --one at a time-- until the problem ceases. The last component you swapped was the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I was convinced it is not a hardware problem, since the guys at the shop I went to ran full diagnostics and said everything is completely fine. Now I'm not sure...
I swapped the power suply cable with another one and no change hapened. 
However, since the last restart the laptop does not turn on at all - just stays at Lenovo screen. I suppose it could a hard drive failure.

Comment: Staying at the manufacturer screen suggests that the machine has failed it's Power On Self Test (POST). Had it been disk failure, you would get a "No operating system found" error *after* POST.

Answer (score -2):

Re install it bro I know your pain bro but it's the best solution.

Don't try to fix it unless you are a developer.

Comment: I did... The same happens.

Comment: I mean do a fresh installation of OS OR MAY it's time to try a new Ubuntu flavour